# how to plot isocline or nullcline of a second order ODE

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, math

I have some code designed to plot an isocline or nullcline of a 2nd order ODE but I keep getting an `ValueError: math domain error`. I will provide the code that I have a picture of what it is supposed to look like. the 2nd order ODE is split into 2 different first order ODE's `dx/dt = f(x,y) = 3x - y^2` and `dy/dt = g(x,y) = sin(y) - x`. this code is designed for any 2nd order ODE but im using the equations in our notes so I make sure that it works before I use it on any other one.

the code is in python 3.8.

**Code**:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

def f(x,y):
    return 3*x-y*y
def g(x,y):
    return math.sin(y) - x

x = []
y = []

def IsoNull(x0, y0, dt, time):  
    x.append(x0)
    y.append(y0)
    for i in range(time):
        x.append(x[i] + (f(x[i],y[i])) * dt)
        y.append(y[i] + (g(x[i],y[i])) * dt)
    return x, y

IsoNull(0.5, 1, 0.01, 1000)

plt.plot(x, 'r-', label='x')
plt.plot(y, 'b-', label='y')
plt.xlabel("time")
plt.legend(loc='best')
```

the error occurs for line 6 of the code "return sin(y) - x

Trying to obtain a plot like this using the above code.

[image: Actual plot]

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow. Nice plot. What's the question?

Comment: Hey,i keep getting the error "value error: math domain error pertaining to 6th line of code "return sin(y) - x". not sure why this is happening, i am aware of why this error generally occurs but not in this case. if i switch the line to sin(x) - y,  i get a graph or sin(y) - y but not the way i have in the original code.                                                                  the graph given one which im trying to obtain, not the one that the code gives.

Comment: What line exactly raises that error? And how come you have a nice plot in your post rather than the error? I don't understand. What code produces the error on what line, and what code doesn't produce the error?

Comment: As far as I know, `math.sin` only raises `ValueError: math domain error` when its argument is `inf` (which you can get as `float('inf')` or `math.inf`).

Comment: what would your solution be to solve this error?. do you have alternatives to getting the solution?

Comment: My guess is that one of the values that you pass to `math.sin` is `inf`. Find out why that happens. When does an `inf` start to appear in your data? Perhaps add `print(i, x[i], y[i])` in the for-loop so we can see what is happening.

Comment: ah yes, it appears that the x and y values go beyong the power of ^221 which then the error occurs. if i set the time value in the from the IsoNull function to less than or equal to 300, the graph appears and setting it to 100 makes it like the actual plot im supposed to get. thanks for your help.